# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 524288) (tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes)

Tags: php, database-connection

The setup

Server : Win7
Database: MSSQLServer 2012
WebServer : IIS
PHP : 5.5
Connection : `$driver="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}`

```
SELECT auditid, Datalength(comments)
FROM tblAudit
ORDER BY 2 desc

278 33152 (Equates to 16576 characters when viewing in Notepad++)
239 22308 (Equates to 11186 characters when viewed in Notepad++)

php memory settings
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
```

php

```
$Comments = odbc_result($rsAudit,"Comments");
```

Works fine for 22308 string length

With 33152

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 524288) (tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes) in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\TramsWeb\php\auditsummary.php on line 235
```

16,576 does not seem like a lot of characters to select in one go, but it is crashing php.

Can anyone advise on a solution to this problem?

Comment: you should start wondering why PHP is trying to allocate 2^32-3 bytes instead of the difference between 22304 and 33152...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess from seeing the number 4294967293 that you're running 32-bit PHP, and it's run into that ~4GB max memory limit error that all 32 bit stuffs suffer from.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a bug with php. There should be no need to allocate that amount of memory just to collect a long string from the database.

Suggestion to move to 64 bit php is a great idea. However I'm relucant to do that as it would require the client to do likewise, and they have other dependencies.

I've devised a workaround that selects the data in 4k chunks and then pieces them all together:

```
function get_comments ($conn,$AuditID,$chunksize,$chunks)
# NRE 24-Jun-2016
# If comments contains over 22308 characters, 32 bit php crashes attempting to collect comments in one go
# Workaround is to split select into chucks then piece them to gether
# Chunksize : size of chunk of data to be grabbed in one go. Testing has indicated can be more more than 4K
# $chunks : Number of sections that comments need to be split into to get all the data
{
  $sSql ="SELECT ";
  $x = 1; 
  $lStart=$x;
  $lEnd=$chunksize;
  # Loop round specified number of chunks, building up sql to collect chunks of the data
  while($x <= $chunks) {
    if ($x>1) {
      # If not first chunk, add comma to split chunk selects
      $sSql = $sSql.", ";
    }
    # SUBSTRING chunk size bit of the data. Alias provided for clarity; is not actively used
    $sSql = $sSql."SUBSTRING(comments, ".$lStart.",".$chunksize.") comments".$x."\r\n";
    $lStart=$lStart+$chunksize;
    $lEnd = $lEnd+$chunksize;
    $x++;
  }
  # Complete the sql
  $sSql = $sSql." FROM tblAudit WHERE AuditID = ".$AuditID;
  $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sSql);
  while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
    $x=1;
    while($x <= $chunks) {
      $Comments = $Comments.odbc_result($rs,$x);    
      $x++;
    }
  }     
  # Return the completed comments
  return $Comments;  
}
```